# Minitest issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this error messages when I ran gem install minitest from the command line

ERROR: Could not find valid gem 'minitest' in any repository (>= 0)in any repository
ERROR: Possible alternatives: minitest.

How do I go about this problem please?

Answer (score -1):

Which version of gem do you have (just  `gem -v` here)

then, try

```
gem list --remote | grep minitest
```

and show the result.

Comment: This should be a comment an not an answer